# Use Stack Overflow where Google is banned

Tags: support, feature-request, bug, google, china

In China, due to some political and social messed-up events, Google is constantly banned by the government-built firewall. So like me living there, if I enter Stack Overflow I will get a red banner displaying

> Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

and I can't use the site normally (like all the JQuery features), even if my browser has loaded JQuery elsewhere already.

I believe this issue has already affected millions of users, mostly those visiting from China I suppose.

I don't need any solution regarding using proxy server or VPN to gain access. These are not real solutions.

In other words, can Stack Overflow provide these "external JS" for backup purpose from its own site?

Comment: also see meta idea about fallback: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133786/add-a-fallback-for-jquery-in-case-it-fails-to-load-from-googles-cdn

Comment: Maybe as a userside solution, someone can invent a greasemonkey/tampermonkey script that replaces the external dependencies with other external dependencies and then only the users in China can use it. This way outside of China everything stays clean and no intervention of SO is needed.

Comment: @Trilarion hey this is a pretty constructive suggestion. I don't know much about this type of script. Does it work like a browser pluggin? so that every site will be injected with the same "selected" dependencies?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I haven't done it before but me or someone else just could try and we would see how much it brings. I guess it would work.